# Should Reset Page be underlined if not what constitutes WCAG rules?

Tags: hyperlinks, best-practice, actions, wcag, reset

I have a reset page text where it returns back to it's last saved state. Should this be underlined? Below you can see an open/close section which I do not have underlined. I know links that navigate somewhere should be underlined or a different color from body text. Considering WCAG does that mean everything needs to be underlined? I haven't found clear info. I feel that it does not need to be underlined but I have seen numerous sites clearing changes underlined also.

[image: Sample page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reset page" is an *action*, and as such really should be a button. And as a button, the [rules for buttons](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/button/) would apply here, which say:

> The types of actions performed by buttons are distinctly different from the function of a link (see link pattern). It is important that both the appearance and role of a widget match the function it provides. Nevertheless, elements occasionally have the visual style of a link but perform the action of a button. In such cases, giving the element role button helps assistive technology users understand the function of the element. **However, a better solution is to adjust the visual design so it matches the function and ARIA role.**

(emphasis added)

Or in other words: Just make the button look like a button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the button option put prefer it without the border would using a ghosted button (no border) satisfy the assistive technology which would see it as a button just without the border.